# Tag Manager and the use of regex when URL contains several different values

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I would like to fire an event in GTM when url contain and matches one of these:
gp01-ppf71743_2, gp01-ppfh1743_2, gp01-epf71743_2, hp01-ppf61743_2, hp01-ppfh1743_2, hp01-epf71743_2, bh01-ppf61743_2, bh01-ppfh1743_2, bh01-epf71743_2

I was thinking that instead of creating several triggers for each value, this could be done using regex? Right or wrong? If so, how would this RegEx look like?

I was thinking "Page URL" -> "Contains" -> "MyRegex".

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score 1):

Rather than figuring out a regex I would recommend that you use the regex table variable type (which requires somewhat less regex skills). Return true for matching substrings, false as default value, and check for that variable in your trigger:

[image]